# RabbitMQ Server Installation

Tags: raspbian, pi-2

I would like easy installation instructions for RabbitMQ Server on my Pi. I tried a lot of things from various sources and they just don't work. One source even said RabbitMQ Server is pre-installed on Raspbian, which is not the case.

More detailed info about my hardware, OS, Kernel, etc...

```
pi@raspberrypi:/bin $ *cat /etc/debian_version*  
9.3  
pi@raspberrypi:/bin $ *cat /etc/os-release*  
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="9"
VERSION="9 (stretch)"
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
pi@raspberrypi:/bin $ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 4.9.59-v7+ #1047 SMP Sun Oct 29 12:19:23 GMT 2017 armv7l GNU/Linux  

pi@raspberrypi:/bin $ *cat /proc/cpuinfo*  
processor   : 0
model name  : ARMv7 Processor rev 5 (v7l)
BogoMIPS    : 38.40
Features    : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt vfpd32 lpae evtstrm 
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant : 0x0
CPU part    : 0xc07
CPU revision    : 5

processor   : 1
model name  : ARMv7 Processor rev 5 (v7l)
BogoMIPS    : 38.40
Features    : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt vfpd32 lpae evtstrm 
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant : 0x0
CPU part    : 0xc07
CPU revision    : 5

processor   : 2
model name  : ARMv7 Processor rev 5 (v7l)
BogoMIPS    : 38.40
Features    : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt vfpd32 lpae evtstrm 
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant : 0x0
CPU part    : 0xc07
CPU revision    : 5

processor   : 3
model name  : ARMv7 Processor rev 5 (v7l)
BogoMIPS    : 38.40
Features    : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt vfpd32 lpae evtstrm 
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant : 0x0
CPU part    : 0xc07
CPU revision    : 5

Hardware    : BCM2835
Revision    : a01041
```

Comment: As you are new here I recommend you take the [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) to find out how things work around here. In future I would advise you to post some detail as to what you have specifically tried and the associated outcomes. It makes it much easier to answer questions as it gives other users an idea as to where to begin with providing an answer.

Comment: How much RAM and disk storage did you have on your Raspberry Pi?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can install it with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install rabbitmq-server
```

I found the package name (**rabbitmq-server**) using apt-cache search:

```
sudo apt-cache search rabbitmq
```

You may also want to read the man (manual page - Linux's help system) pages for **apt-get** and **apt-cache** commands:

`man apt-get` and `man apt-cache`.

Comment: Thanks! That worked. Don’t know why I did t try this simpler method instead of going to the web and getting all sorts of complicated solutions!

Answer (score 5):

The approved answer did not work for me with Stretch. If it does work it will give you an older version. I tried a lot of different things to get the latest version and this was the only one I found that worked. From the instructions on this page https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-debian.html

`curl -s https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/script.deb.sh | sudo bash
sudo apt-get install rabbitmq-server
sudo systemctl enable rabbitmq-server
sudo systemctl start rabbitmq-server
sudo rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management`

In your web browser go to `http://<IP of PI>:15672/`

Comment: It is a very big security hole to run blindly a bash script with root rights coming direct from the internet.

Comment: @Ingo I don't think it's particularly rare nor troubling in this case given that the  script comes from the package authors anyway. Node.js uses this method too if you want to install a more recent version than what the Debian repos provide. It's worth being wary, but in this case it seems safe and is an official method so nothing to worry about.

Comment: @Aurora0001 I know comments are not for discussion but if I were a hacker I would scan the internet for such methods to compromise them and I would prefer distinguished authors ...

Comment: @Ingo you are welcome to provide an alternate answer. This is from the rabbitmq website so if you don't trust this script then you probably don't want to trust the authors of rabbitmq at all. BTW, the script is there for everyone to see, and is not that long so you can verify it if you so desire.

Comment: @MikeKulls Now we have the debate about security and carelessness in the internet :-/ It isn't that I do not trust the author. It is that I don't trust the internet in general.  There are professional hackers there. Why do we have so much huge bot nets on the internet with millions of zombies? It is because of the carelessness of the users and the authors. The author has to provide an alternate answer (maybe with a hash?) not I. And to be a comment to improve your answer: I suggest to edit your answer and note to inspect the script before blindly execute it (may not help newbies). EOD.

Comment: @Ingo I mean if you don't like my answer you are welcome to provide a better one. Very few zombies would come from open source websites. I have never seen or heard a case of this. EOD lol

Comment: I should add that if they are going to hack this script then they could also hack the RabbitMQ source code, so I wouldn't run any open source software on your computer ever if I was you :-)

Comment: @Ingo your concern applies to every public repo including github and sf.

Comment: @MikeKulls Did this work for you?  Which instructions did you follow to install Erlang?

Comment: These were the instructions I used. I believe Erlang gets installed as a dependency.

Comment: Hi @MikeKulls I followed your instruction, but I still got RabbitMQ 3.7.8 Erlang 21.2.6 installed, which is same with what I got from the website. I tested, I still cannot connect my local running Rabbit MQ server from a client e.g. Mqtt Dash(Android App). Could you help?

Comment: @Franva does the URL for rabbitMQ work? Is it running with "systemctl status rabbitmq-server"

Comment: hi @MikeKulls I figured it out, I missed running ```sudo rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_mqtt```, after this, my mqtt started working