# Cannot connect RabbitMQ server from client side

Tags: raspbian, pi-4, raspbian-buster, mqtt

I followed [this link](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/87244/113946) to install RabbitMQ server on my Raspberry Pi 4.

I can see that RabbitMQ 3.7.8 and Erlang 21.2.6 are installed.

[image]

But I cannot connect to the server from a client (Mqtt Dash, Android app)
[image]

Can someone share some ideas?

---

Update 1

```
sudo systemctl enable rabbitmq-server
sudo systemctl start rabbitmq-server
sudo rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management
```

I have run the above commands to enable and start the mqtt and tried both 1883 and 8883 on the Mqtt Dashboard app, still have no luck.

Comment: Port 15672 is a bit odd for MQTT. It normally runs on 1883 & 8883. So take a look with `sudo netstat -tlnpu | grep rabbit`.

Comment: Full list of ports used are https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-debian.html#ports 15672 is for http clients. Dougie is correct (as normal with MQTT) in saying the ports for MQTT client are these but the plugin needs to be enabled as per https://www.rabbitmq.com/mqtt.html

Comment: hi @Dougie tried, no output. any ideas? I also tried ports 1883 and 8883, they all failed. Is there any information you need to debug?

Comment: hi @Andyroo I have run commands to enable and start my rabbit mq server. Please see my update 1. Let me know if you need more information for debugging. thanks

Comment: Can you access the Pi from your phone via any app (Fing is good for finding devices on the network). If so Try the port as 1883 and no user / password

Comment: hi @Andyroo I can connect to Pi from my Windows 10 Remote Desktop. I have figured it out. will update as the answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @Andyroo for sharing [the link](https://www.rabbitmq.com/mqtt.html)

I found I missed one command to run:

```
rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_mqtt
```

So overall, I ran these following commands:

```
sudo systemctl enable rabbitmq-server
sudo systemctl start rabbitmq-server
sudo rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management
sudo rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_mqtt
```